# jQuery: main memory getting too high when loading images

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, memory-leaks

My web apps displays a livestream using AJAX. In fact we use jquery to load a new image from the server every 50 millisecons.
The problem is that the browser (google chrome) needs increasing main memory as long as the livestream is started. This lasts for about 20 minutes then the systems lags very much and the browser consumes far over 1GB of RAM.

The follwing code is used to load the images from the server into a html  element:

```
img = $( defaultWebcamHtml ).attr('src', urlImage + new Date().getTime() + imageExtension)
        .load(function() {
            if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
                console.log('[Error] Broken image!');
            } else {
                if(!(img === null)) {
                    $(htmlImgId).replaceWith(img); // if you comment this line out the problem seems to stop
                }
            }
            isLoading = false;
        });
```

The bug seems to occur in google chrome and firefox but not IE.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? - I'm experiencing the same problem

Comment: @Hackeron Not really but it gets better since I load a new image from the server and draw it on a html canvas element instead of using a img element

Comment: Can you please post an example of your current code to handle this?